# how to calculate positive number and negative number in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sample table in Excel below. How do I sum up the total Win row and Loss row from week1 through week3 as below: I use the auto sum option, but the result did not work as I wanted. Would someone share the idea?

```
week       az     tx     ca
week1      1       2      1
week2     -1      -2      3
week3      1       1     -3
Win        2       1      1
Loss      -1      -2     -3
```

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the Win & loss rows? Is the table an example of what you want? If so what I can not see what you are trying to do, I do not see a pattern. az,Win = sum of positives; ca, Win = sum of positives; **tx,Win = sum of all**; Losses = sum of negatives. Please edit question, to make it clearer.

Comment: Agree with @richard. What is the logic behind the Win results?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sum up all the negative values, you can use Sumif()

=SUMIF(A2:A4,"<0")

The logic for the "win" row is not clear. Your data does not make sense. Either simply do a `=Sum(A2:A4)` to arrive at a grand total, or sum only the positive values with

=SUMIF(A2:A4,">0")

Answer (score 1):

First sum all the values, positive and negative, across each column. Then sum the absolute values in each column. The difference is twice the amount of the losses. So you can do something like the following.

```
 losses = -(SUM(ABS(*field*)) - SUM(*field*))/2
```

Once you know the losses you can subtract the losses twice from the sum of absolutes.

```
 wins = SUM(ABS(*field*)) + 2*losses
```

(The plus is, because we defined the losses to be negative themselve.)
I think that should do the trick.

Of course it can be done using if statements. I just think this version is more elegant.